# Finding out the position of an exception while processing a file

Tags: python, exception

I'm processing some semi-structured documents in Python and I have some code that reads the file into a tuple and loops through each line and performs a function. Is there a way of finding the exact line in the processed file where an error is encountered?

```
c = tuple(open("file", 'r'))

for element in c:
    if (condition is met):
        do something
    else:
        do something else
```

The result should be:

```
Error: in line # of "file"
```

Comment: Well, you're looping over lines of the file so you could do `for line_number, line in enumerate(c, start=1):`

Comment: The exception doesn't carry local variables, much less other state like the internals of the `TextIOWrapper`, much less internal state that doesn't even exist like a line number. But you can easily add it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) should help:

```
for line, element in enumerate(c):
    try:
        if (condition is met):
            do something
        else:
            do something else
    except Exception as e:
        print('got error {!r} on line {}'.format(e, line))
```

The above would give an error like:

```
got error OSError('oops!',) on line 4
```

Although as good practice you'd generally replace `Exception` with whatever error you're expecting to catch.

Comment: I'd either use `{!r}` or throw the exception type into the error manually. It's frustrating when you get a log message about an exception and have to guess what type it was. (But otherwise, great answer.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is good practice to use the `with` keyword when you are reading from a file, especially if you expect an Exception to occur. You can also `enumerate` to count the lines:

`with open(filename) as f:
        for line_num, line in enumerate(f):
            try:
                if (condition is met):
                    do something
                else:
                    do something else
             except Exception:
                 print('Error: in line {:d} of file'.format(line_num))`

It's best to not use `Exception` if you know the specific Exception you are expecting because it will catch all Exceptions, even those you don't expect.